# ImageView zooming is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have an ImageView zoom application ran on my  mobile, when I first run it, the image work and the zooming as well,  after that, I made a link button to the image view, with the same  previous application, the image appears but no zooming for it and it  doesn't move at all

Can someone help?

mapslocations.xml

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/pslook1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Map"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Sites.java

```
package com.f.fa;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Sites extends Activity {
    ImageView imageDetail1;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    PointF startPoint = new PointF();
    PointF midPoint = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapslocations);
        imageDetail1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pslook1);
        /**
         * set on touch listner on image
         */
        imageDetail1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                System.out.println("matrix=" + savedMatrix.toString());
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                    oldDist = spacing(event);

                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        midPoint(midPoint, event);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x, event.getY() - startPoint.y);
                    } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                }
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                return true;
            }

            @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
            private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            }

            private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

imageview1.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pslook1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/powerstationwallmap" />
```

PagePowerstation.java

```
package com.f.fa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PagePowerstation extends Activity {

    Button imageview1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imageview1);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use android:layout_width="wrap_content"instead of android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: curious_mind, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom `TouchImageView`:

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

    Matrix matrix;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;

    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    /* */
    private void stopInterceptEvent()
    {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }

    private void startInterceptEvent()
    {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        stopInterceptEvent();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);

                            float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];

                            if((int) (getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale) + fixTransX) == 0)
                                startInterceptEvent();
                            else
                                stopInterceptEvent();
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        startInterceptEvent();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            //Fit to screen.
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }
}
```

Use in XML:

```
<your_package_name.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialogImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Pratik Butani, same thing as the previews answer.. when I did it at the beginning, it worked, when I added a button link, the image opened but I can't zoom.