# how to set image view in center when i apply pinch zoom on it?

Tags: android, pinchzoom

i want to set image on center when i apply properties like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainContainerDialog"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/color_screen_bg" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_login_selector"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/title_cancel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProductImageDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_app_bg_logo" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

but my image view always start upper left corner like below images.

[image]

i want this image view in center and then apply pinch zoom on this image view.

Comment: Use https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25606398/1318946

Comment: `android:scaleType="matrix"` change it to `android:scaleType="center"` to set the Image in center

Comment: @SilentKiller change it to android:scaleType="center" but zoomin and zoomout not working.

Comment: @Roadies post the entire xml..

Comment: What you had done for zoomin and zoomout .? PratikButani has given sample link for that. please try that answer

Comment: zoomin and zoomout working fine when i put android:scaleType="matrix" but i want just image center not upper left corner.

Comment: @SilentKiller i will check answer.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar your link is helpful thanks..

Comment: @PratikButani thanks your class is also help full for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TouchImageView.java in this Code

[TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use : **RelativeLayout**, use: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

or

`android:layout_gravity="center"` to your ImageView

or

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_login_selector"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/title_cancel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

     <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProductImageDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_app_bg_logo" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivProductImageDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_app_bg_logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/*The ImageView is Centered by X,Y*/ />
```